# Conditional SQL Join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements

I have to create a query that verifies if a column is not null and join using it, but if it's null I must to join another column.

if was possible, must be something like that

```
SELECT A FROM DBTEST

IF ( NOT B = NULL)
INNER JOIN DBTEST2.B = DBTEST.B
ELSE
INNER JOIN DBTEST2.C = DBTEST.B
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT a 
FROM   dbtest 
       JOIN dbtest2 
         ON dbtest.b = dbtest2.b 
UNION ALL 
SELECT a 
FROM   dbtest 
       JOIN dbtest2 
         ON dbtest.b = dbtest2.c 
WHERE  dbtest2.b IS NULL
```

This will probably perform better than using a case expression inside the join condition, as the optimiser will be able to choose appropriate indexes if they exist, or at least to choose a join method based on the table structures.

Comment: at least u should add condition JOIN DBTEST2 ON DBTEST.B = DBTEST2.B where DBTEST2.B is not null

Comment: @Dhaval No I shouldn't.  You can't join on something that's null, so the extra condition would add nothing.

Answer (score 6):

This should work

```
SELECT A 
FROM DBTEST 
Inner join DBTEST2 
on DBTEST.B = case when DBTEST2.B is null then DBTEST2.C else DBTEST2.B end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a 
FROM   dbtest 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Isnull(dbtest2.b, dbtest2.c) Col 
                   FROM   dbtest2)TT 
               ON TT.col = dbtest.b
```

I think this may solve your problem